# Trying to run Tomcat on port 80

Tags: tomcat7, apache2.2

Apache HTTPD 2.2, Apache Tomcat 7, Windows 7.

My servlet returns html pages constructed via XSL / XML and xalan.jar / xerces.jar.

I can run my servlet on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myServlet` and it returns the page correctly. However the linked css files aren't found or used.

If I look for the css files using `http://127.0.0.1/myServlet/css/blah/blah/screen.css`, then its contents is visible to the browser.

On a previous instalation I was able to run `http://127.0.0.1/myServlet` and it would see the css files and return the page corectly too.

I've obviously not set up something right in the configuration of either HTTPD or Tomcat.

Comment: How are you linking the CSS files? Simple HTML tags within the page (HTML) that the servlet is returning to the browser?

Comment: Default HTTP is port `80`. You can setup the port you want Tomcat to be using for HTTP by going in the `server.xml` config file and finding the `Connector` using protocol `HTTP/1.1`. There's a `port` attribute you can modify.

Comment: Munyul: yes they are "simple" HTML tags in the returned document.

Comment: Sotirios: I have played about with the server.xml file and the connector but the things I've tried didn't work.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have anpother go at the server.xml file ....

Comment: I've tried adding Listen 8080 to Apache, I've tried adding connectors for 80 and setting it as a proxy for 127.0.0.1:8080, I've tried haviong connectors for both 80 and 8080 and removed the Listen settings. Nothing appears to work. any other ideas please?